# How to do some code every time that IIS restart

Tags: c#, iis, httpmodule

I have a static list of data.
I want to fill this list with the data every time that doing restart to IIS
meaning: fill the list before someone enter to the site.

can anyone give ne an answere???

I heared about "warm-up-module" ...but i dont know how to use it..

Comment: Maybe you need the app start event, not sure

Comment: The site doesn't actually start until someone visits it - or at least until something makes a request of it, so pretty difficult to load data prior to that. Unless you want to put a lot of work into it, your best bet is to load data the first time its required and then cache it. Yes that means the first request is slow, but then thats true of just about any site.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WebActivator (available as nuget package) to execute some code when your web-app is started.

Or use Application_Start() in the global.asax.

Comment: I tried to put my code in Application_Start() but when i did restart to the IIS ,nothing happened!!!

Comment: the Application_Start() happened just after I entered to the site in the browser!

Answer (score 1):

Can you just implement the data as a singleton property?

```
private object myListOfData;

object MyListOfData
{
    get
    {
        if (myListOfData == null)
            myListOfData = CodeYouWantToRunOnIisResart();

        return myListOfData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Singletons are evil and definitely not needed in this case

Comment: You can write this code like this : `private Lazy<MyData> m_Data = new Lazy<MyData>(GetMyData());public MyData Data { get { return m_Data.Value; } }`

Comment: @lboshuizen Care to elaborate rather than just saying they are evil? btw I'd say the Application_Start() in global.asax is probably the best, but my answer is probably one of the simplest

Comment: Why Singletons are Evil? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx as an example

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application_Start event` in the `global.asax`.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473(v=vs.100).aspx

Sample

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      // Code that runs on application startup
}
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.biztalk.kwtpm.tppubwebservice.global.application_start(v=bts.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use IServiceBehavior Interface.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iservicebehavior.aspx

Comment: Please provide more than just a link in your answer. If the link ever breaks your post won't help future users.